# How do you appropriately measure the real mean squared error of a box cox transformed linear regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, mathematics, mse

My understanding is that it can make sense to transform the outcomes of a linear regression model to make them more normally distributed. That's because it could 1) help me find more linear relationships between predictor variables and the outcome I want to predict and 2) prevent extreme values from making a model less accurate.

So I boxcox transformed the outcome variable I'm trying to predict. (charges)

```
transformed_charges, lambda_ = stats.boxcox(charges)
```

I've created what I imagine is a fairly ordinary linear regression model.

```py
X = insurance_with_dummies[['smoker_yes', 'age']]
y = insurance_with_dummies['transformed_charges']

# set the random seed to a fixed value
# np.random.seed(0) # I'm not sure this is doing anything.

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
print(X_train)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_train)
coef = model.coef_
print(coef) # [2.31854023 0.05127261] 

r_squared = model.score(X_train, y_train)
print(f'R-squared: {r_squared}')

# try the r2_score function
r_two_score = r2_score(y_train, predictions)
print(r_two_score)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_train, predictions)
print(mse)
```

I'm aware mse above refers to the mean squared error of the predictions of the box-cox transformed error. I want to know what the model's mean squared error is for predictions of the actual outcome.

I'm not clear if I'm supposed to get that by doing this:

```
from scipy.special import inv_boxcox

print(inv_boxcox(mse, lambda_)) # 1.6088711396604742
```

or this:

```
outcomes_real_scale = inv_boxcox(y_train,lambda_)
predictions_real_scale = inv_boxcox(predictions,lambda_)
mse_real_scale = mean_squared_error(outcomes_real_scale, predictions_real_scale)
print(mse_real_scale) # 65371079.65670876
```

The first way gives me a mean squared error of 1.6 which sounds great, while the second way gives me a mean squared error of over 65 million which seems awful.

How should I interpret these numbers? Is one of them the true mean squared error?

Comment: "I'm aware mse above refers to the mean squared error of the predictions of the box-cox transformed error"  Where did you perform that transformation in your code?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects In the first code block in my post. ```transformed_charges, lambda_ = stats.boxcox(charges)```

Comment: easier to follow if all in one place imo   ill look again later